# Loop to read doubles inputted from a user

Tags: java, loops

So i have a program which is reading doubles inputted from a user, however, if the user does not input any data at the beginning, i want to print a message as so:

Enter data set:

^D

No data!

However when i run my program and when the user inputs values and then presses ctl+d, even though there are values inputted the program still gives the No Data message. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter data set: ");
    ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
        nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
    }
    //I think this is the part that is causing the bug but im not sure how to fix it
    if (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("\nNo Data!");
        return;
    }
```

How can i mody this program so that only when the user doesnt input any data does the message print, rather than all the time whenever the user ends the file? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 if (nums.isEmpty ()) {
```

as your condition maybe?

Comment: I have to wait 5 minutes before i can click the tick to accept this answer :P But i surely will

Answer (score 1):

you need to check is elements are present in the list checking the method [List.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty())

according the java doc:

```
boolean isEmpty()
```

> Returns true if this list contains no elements.

## Example:

```
if (nums.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("\nNo Data!");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter data set: ");
        ArrayList<Double> nums = new ArrayList<Double>();

    do {
        try {
            double temp = keyboard.nextDouble();
            nums.add(temp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

    } while (true);

    keyboard.close();

    if (nums.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("\nNo Data!");
    }
}
}

$ java Test
Enter data set: 
1.2
2.3
$ java Test
Enter data set: 
^D
No Data!
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Jan's answer, whats happening is when the code executes this:

```
while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
        nums.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
 }
```

It goes through all the tokens(that are double) in the Scanner till there is none left. After that when the execution comes to your **if** condition:

```
if (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("\nNo Data!");
    return;
}
```

It has no more Double tokens to go through, and hence, the condition fails and the message displays.

Comment: Thank you @blobmarley, that makes more sense now!